# Query de histórico SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, histórico

estou precisando de uma ajuda com SQL. Preciso fazer uma query que me devolva um histórico da data atual até 7 dias pra trás. Alguem poderia me ajudar por favor?

Comment: O que você já conseguiu até agora? Mostre-nos a query que você tentou.

Comment: Aproveita e conta qual é o banco de dados que você está usando.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se você deseja buscar a partir da data atual, você não precisar informar nenhuma variável de data. MySQL é inteligente :), e é capaz de fazer a conta de quando é sete dias no passado.

### Faça assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabela 
WHERE 
  data BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-7 AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

`BETWEEN` retorna o que há entre essas datas.

`CURRENT_DATE()` retorna a data atual.

`CURRENT_DATE()-7` retorna a data atual, menos sete dias.

Referências:

- [MySQL Comparison Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)
- [MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

No SQL Server a função para data funciona assim:

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Data Atual menos 7 dias:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Desde que seja MySql que o @Brunão esteja utilizando.

Comment: Exato não havia pensado nisso

Comment: Muito obrigado Otto....estou utilizando o SQL Server...

Comment: Alguma idéia de como fazer isso enviando os parâmetros via Java?

Comment: Se você vai fazer na query não importa a linguagem de programação que esta usando Certo ?